# i want to enable push notification in android app & gcm_defaultSenderId error didn't remove in android studio

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to enable the GCM for Push Notifications, like exchanging information (via message).

But in `RegistrationIntentService.java` class gcm_defaultSenderId error can not resolve, I will put my sender_id which is provided from console.developers.google.com.
please help me out.

[image: Error Link]

Comment: have you copied `google-services.json`?

Comment: have you declare `gcm_defaultSenderId` in `string.xml` in `values` folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare your GCM default sender id in strings.xml.
In your project folder res->values->strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">XXXXXXXXXX</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in **res>values>string.xml** you should declare *gcm_defaultSenderId* like this :

**string.xml**

```
<string name="gcm_defaultSenderId">your sender id</string>
```